# Disable Trash on a specific drive

Tags: optical-drive, trash

Is there a possibility of disabling the trash-bin for a drive and deleting files instantly?
I'm using DVD-RAM as a backup solution and trashing files is producing a lot of additional, unnecessary writes on the backup discs as the files are moved to a new location and then overwritten on delete from the trash bin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found a solution for this on the web while waiting for the timelimit on creating questions:

You just need to open terminal, go to the drive you want the trash-bin to be disabled on and then do this:

```
sudo rm -rf .Trashes
touch .Trashes
```

Essentially what this does is deleting the trash-bin recursively and replacing it with an empty file thus blocking OSX from recreating it. When you delete files after that OSX will ask you about instant deletion instead of putting it into the trash-bin. Works perectly.

Comment: What permissions did you add to /Volumes/whatever/.Trashes to keep finder out?

Comment: You don't need to have any special permissions as you're replacing a directory with a file and finder can't use a file as a location for the trash-bin.

Comment: This is emptying trash, not disabling the trash feature.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer possible as of 2022 / Monterey: `rm: .Trashes: Operation not permitted`